# if same columns values are repeated in multiple rows then UPDATE - SQL / MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

- If the **same column** values are repeated in the **multiple rows**
- then **delete** the **whole row** based on the **column value** and
- **update** the new row ( that is other column values ) based on the **same column value**

I have a table like this

```
create table if not exists cms(
  id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
  cms_id varchar(20),
  published_datetime varchar(30),
  last_modified_datetime varchar(30),
  score float,
  access_vector varchar(45),
  access_complexity varchar(45),
  authentication varchar(45),
);


INSERT INTO `cms` (`id`, `cms_id`, `published_datetime`, `last_modified_datetime`, `score`, `access_vector`, `access_complexity`, `authentication`) VALUES
(1, 'CMS-2002-0493', '2002-08-12T00:00:00.000-04:00', '2016-10-24T11:23:01.940-04:00', 7.5, 'NETWORK', 'LOW', 'NONE')
```

[image]

- now in this table I don't want to allow duplicate values for the
  column named **cms_id**
- For this I don't want to set unique key for the column **cms_id**
  because this  column value will be repeated then based on this column value     **cms_id** the other column values could be changed
- That is **cms_id** could be same where other columns could get
  different entries
- each time with the same **cms_id** values other columns in the row may different entries

in simple words if same value of **cms_id** gets repeated then update the whole row (update all columns based on **cms_id**)

now I need an output like only the last inserted cms_id value should be present in table other all same cms_id should be deleted and updated with last entry

coulmn id with primary key 1,613,1225 should be deleted and only 1837 should be present

I need output something like below image

[image]

totally it should replace the repeated **cms_id** column as per last entry.

accordingly if **cms_id** value repeats then it should delete the existing **cms_id** value and it should update all the other column values as per last insert entry , need query for this

Comment: A trigger would probably work, but I'm not familiar with those. Using a scripting language to do this might not be a bad idea either.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a special `REPLACE` command that works exactly like `INSERT` except it replaces the row if the primary key or an unique has the same value.

```
REPLACE INTO cms ...
```

Where ... represents the rest of the query.

*Disclaimer: This SQL statement is a special extension made by MySQL; it is not part of the SQL standard and probably won't work on other DBMS.*